How to save or autosave creatable and movable divs when reloading a local page?
The page im experimenting with is like a simple notes page where you click a button to create divs that are movable on the page. So i want these divs to stay on the page when i reload it. How would i go about solving this issue in the best way? Ive experimented alot with localStorage but without success.
Here is simplified version of how i create and move them:


window.onload = function() {
   
    var iscklick = 0;
 
    function trigger(id){
       let tempid = "#div_" + id;
       $(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
          if(isclick){
          $(tempid).css({'top':event.pageY - $('#div_' + id).outerHeight() /2, 'left':event.pageX - $(tempid).outerHeight() /2});    
          }
       //mouseup makes it unstick and cleans tempid
       }).on('mouseup',function(){
          isclick = 0;
          tempid = ""
       })
     }
 
    $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $(".container").on('mouseover', '.element', function(){
          var id = this.id;
          var split_id = id.split("_");
          var finalid = split_id[1];
          //mousedown triggers func
          $("#div_" + finalid).on('mousedown', function(){
             isclick = 1;
             trigger(finalid);
                 
          })
       })
 
       $(".add").click(function(){
             
          var lastid = $(".element:last").attr("id");
          var split_id = lastid.split("_");
          var nextindex = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;
      
          $(".element:last").after("<div class='element' id='div_"+ nextindex +"'></div>");
     
          $("#div_" + nextindex).append("");           
             
       });
    });
 };
html, body{
    background-color:lightgray;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.add {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background-color: rgb(105, 230, 188);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px darkslategray;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 70%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    top:45%;
    margin: 2%;
}
.add:active{
    background-color: rgb(45, 138, 107);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px darkslategray;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
.element{
    position:absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(172, 172, 106);
    margin: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.element:hover{
    z-index: 1;
}
#div_1{
    display: none;
}
<!doctype html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <button class='add'>+</button>
        <div class="container" >
            <div class='element' id='div_1'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



Thanks in advance, im just trying to learn how to save states in jquery.
Ive tried alot of localStorage and looked into cookies but i dont really understand what the best way is to tackle this issue when there are so many things that need to be saved. I also plan on adding loads more and basically everything that the user does needs to stick after you reload the page.

Ive posted a snippet of it so you can see what i mean. What i want to know is how to save all the newly created divs and their positions.

You have to use localStorage, but the catch is that you have to save your container HTML to it.
You need to do it on the add button click as well as on the trigger() function called (to save HTML with positions)
Here is the working snippet:
window.onload = function() {

  var iscklick = 0;

  function trigger(id) {
    let tempid = "#div_" + id;
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (isclick) {
        $(tempid).css({
          'top': event.pageY - $('#div_' + id).outerHeight() / 2,
          'left': event.pageX - $(tempid).outerHeight() / 2
        });
        localStorage.setItem("tabelaContent", $(".container").html());
      }
      //mouseup makes it unstick and cleans tempid
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
      isclick = 0;
      tempid = ""
    })
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("tabelaContent") !== null) {
      $(".container").html(localStorage.getItem("tabelaContent"));
    }
    $(".container").on('mouseover', '.element', function() {
      var id = this.id;
      var split_id = id.split("_");
      var finalid = split_id[1];
      //mousedown triggers func
      $("#div_" + finalid).on('mousedown', function() {
        isclick = 1;
        trigger(finalid);

      })
    })

    $(".add").click(function() {

      var lastid = $(".element:last").attr("id");
      var split_id = lastid.split("_");
      var nextindex = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

      $(".element:last").after("<div class='element' id='div_" + nextindex + "'></div>");

      $("#div_" + nextindex).append("");
      localStorage.setItem("tabelaContent", $(".container").html());
    });
  });
};

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/5ep9v3kr/

You can consider using localStorage which will work for the user, without losing its saved state when the user's session is destroyed. Or you can use sessionStorage which stores data for the current session.
To be agnostic, I will use the term myStorage and you replace it with localStorage or sessionStorage, depending on your preference.
Things to know:

myStorage.setItem(key, value) sets the value to be stored as key, for example myStorage.setItem('name', 'John Doe'), you will need to pass a string to this one, so you might need to do JSON.stringify(thestuff)
myStorage.getItem(key) returns the string that was stored at the key, defaulting to null. If you want to work with something else than a string, then you will need to parse this back, via JSON.parse(thestuff) or your parsing functionalities

The other answer suggests storing the HTML inside your storage, but that's wasting memory and it's a rather volatile approach, because if you change your HTML, then all the already stored HTMLs will be invalid when they are loaded back.
Instead, I strongly suggest to:

implement a function to getDataFromHTML(thehtml)
implement a function to getHTMLFromData(thedata)
store stuff via myStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(thekey, getDataFromHTML(thehtml)))
load stuff via myStorage.getItem(JSON.parse(thekey))

Of course, it's your responsibility to get the HTML, find the data from an HTML and specify your key.
